# Having trouble strategizing my donation system with PayPal

Tags: php, redirect, paypal-ipn, eclipse-pdt

I want users to enter a donation amount, press donate, have it automatically redirect them back to a page where they enter their in-game username and boom, they're done.

I was originally going to use IPN, but it apparently does not auto return. When I enable auto-return, it doesn't pass the variables, it simply redirects.

Then I saw somewhere that I should use PDT, which is a whole-nother world to me. I don't see nearly as much tutorials on it or even testing tools from PayPal. Which makes me believe that's not what I should be doing.

Can someone guide me as to how I should setup a system that works how I described at the very beginning? I want it to require minimal user interaction. Just enter the donation amount, submit, enter their username, done.

Comment: Missed the big "DO NOT USE" on [tag:automatic], huh?

Comment: @minitech Yes, as it does not tell you when you write the tag.

Comment: It actually does, though. (Unless you're using Internet Explorer 8. In which case... my sincerest condolences.)

Comment: @minitech Then yes, I did. I don't see why that's the only help you could provide. You could've simply stated that you have nothing to offer on this sort of subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Buttons for donations](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside) Paypal web page, where you can find the wizard to create the button, as well as any relevant code associated with it.

**See also:** [Getting Started With Donate Buttons](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons)

With Paypal advanced features you can customize the return address for your web-site and much more:

See [Page 2 – Specifying Advanced Features of Your Donate Button](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons#id08AAF0RH0WS)

---

For a more personalized user experience, you can look at [HTML Variables for Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) where is documented the parameters used to interact with Paypal an allow you to use your own HTML environment (till a certain point...).

Comment: Could I just ask them for their username with the donation form, and then use Javascript to copy the entered username to the 'custom' PayPal form field before submitting?

Comment: No, you can't interact with Paypal as freely as you would with a form of your own. You need to use their API to interact with their services.

Comment: You can take a look at [HTML Variables for Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) to see if any fits your needs.

Comment: I just tried it out and it works. They enter their name in a field, press MY submit button, then jQuery transfers the data in the visible field to the hidden PayPal "custom" field, and submits the PayPal form.

Comment: Yes, that type of manipulation you can do, but its is not advised by Paypal!

Comment: I have many integrated Paypal solutions and all are fully personalized to fit the websites environments, but the final moment, where the users actually authenticates to Paypal and performs the Payment is always managed by Paypal.

Comment: I understand, but it's either spending 10 minutes to invent a Javascript-based system, or spending a few hours to do the same thing with extra steps :P